# Flex 4.5 skinnable container generic skin

Tags: apache-flex, generics, skinning, scroller

How can I write a generic skin and use it for multiple containers.
Say, I have different border containers, with different background gradients. I want to write a single skin file and use it in all border containers to apply different gradients.

How can I get scrollers for resolution independent flex web app, where I use only percentage widths and heights for all groups and containers.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused.  It sounds like you are asking three questions in one.  Perhaps you should separate this into multiple questions?  Also, you should expand on what you want to do.  You want to write a generic skin and use it for multiple containers.  What containers do you want to use it for?